# How to track in Entry Framework that Record has been created successfully .NET Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core-2.0

I am working on .NET CORE 2.0 entity framework side of application.

I have following code to insert new record in database that is new user with specific role, that is working fine but I need to know how to monitor that record been created successfully? and state of entry

```
 bool recordCreated = false;

        try
        {
            UserDataModel userWithDefaultRoleObj = new UserDataModel();

            userWithDefaultRoleObj = new UserDataModel
            {
                Id = initializeNewUserWithRole.UserId,
                Name = initializeNewUserWithRole.Name,
                Surname = initializeNewUserWithRole.Surname,
                Email = initializeNewUserWithRole.Email,
                Roles = new List<UserRoleDataModel>
                {
                    new UserRoleDataModel {
                        Role = Context.Roles.Where(roleName => roleName.Name == initializeNewUserWithRole.RoleName).First(),
                        User = userWithDefaultRoleObj
                    }
                }
            };

            //var addRecordState = Context.Add<UserDataModel>(userWithDefaultRoleObj).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added;

            var addRecordState = Context.Add<UserDataModel>(userWithDefaultRoleObj);                
            var x = Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why would it not get created? You either have a new record or you have an exception to deal with.

Comment: Well you have the EntityEntry (from the Context.Add) - after save you can check that the state is Unchanged... unless there's something we're not getting about your question?